# bold square root with bm

Tags: math-mode, bold

I use the `bm` package.

This is the expression I use:

```
\bm{A=\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}
```

My letters are bold as expected, but the square root is thinner and more ugly than without `\bm`.

Everything looks fine when using

```
\bm{A=\sqrt{C}}
```

So I guess it has something to do with space.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: are you loading `amsmath`? If yes, you need to put the `\sqrt{}` macro in braces, like this: `$\bm{A={\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}}$`. Then it'll work. See page 9 of the `bm` manual.

Comment: @dcmst page 9? actually \sqrt seems to need {} whether or not amsmath loaded, I'm sure it didn't used to

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yup, you're right, it needs `{}` in both cases. I tried only the working cases without amsmath (like `\sqrt{C}`) and they obviously worked. This, plus I think I misread the referenced page.

Comment: I forgot to load amsmath... I also put braces around \sqrt{}. Now it works! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @dcmst see my answer :(

Answer (score 5):

Ah.

This can not possibly be a bug, so it must be a (only slightly) documented feature.

As mentioned in the `bm` manual, commands with optional arguments are locally modified inside `\bm` specifically so that `\bm{\sqrt{xyz}}` works.  To see why you need `\bm{{\sqrt{...}}}` with an extra pair of braces in your example, consider:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{1x}$ 

$\sqrt{2x^2}$

$\sqrt{3x\strut^2}$

$\bm{\sqrt{4x^2}}$

$\bm{\sqrt{5x}}$

$\bm{{\sqrt{6x^2}}}$

\boldmath

$\sqrt{7x^2}$

$\sqrt{8x\strut^2}$

\end{document}
```

Looking at the relevant bit of the log file

```
$ grep \\\\OM[SX] bm111.log 
......\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 p
......\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 p
......\OMX/cmex/m/n/5 q
......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/10 p
......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/10 p
.........\OMS/cmsy/b/n/10 p
......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/10 p
......\OMX/cmex/m/n/5 q
```

You can see that "small" radicals come from the symbol font `OMS/cmsy/m` which has a bold version installed `OMS/cmsy/b` but large radicals come from the symbol extension font `OMX/cmex/m` which in the standard Computer Modern font set doesn't have a bold version.
Your case with a superscripted capital is on a tipping point, if `bm` sets it all together (due to the extra braces) the cramped style is used, the radical gets chosen from cmsy and goes bold, but without the extra help the radical comes from cmex for which there is no bold font.